# How do I use small html markup repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html, header, reusability

I am working on standalone JavaScript application which is being coded in HTML 5.
It has almost 50-60 html pages including repetitive markup such as header, footer and nav.
But if I have to make change in header then I have to make changes in 56-60 pages.

**Is there any solution to use reusable html markup so if I did changes in one page it will reflect to other pages?**

I can't even use php.

Comment: Hmmm... iframes would allow you to do that, but would be crazy. You can try and create these elements via JS. Try also this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes, it includes a "Client Side Includes" section that you could try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prepare one `javascript` function. Write your `html elements` through `javascript` or `jquery` function. run it in `page load event`. and call the function in html by `div`.

Put this `javascript function` in separate `.js` file. And call this `js` file in wherever you want. And just place the `div` wherever you want in the `html` page.

See this jsfiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6UAmH/)

I Hope this demo will useful to you in this situation.

Comment: I am agree with you but I think this will not be final solution

Comment: @user2130962 What you exactly want?

Comment: @user2130962 come to this chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/concrete5-javascript-jquery-php-and-mysql-issues

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML (.html) pages and do not have Server-Side-Includes option then you can use a JavaScript template (which is not too difficult).

Second option : use of iframe.

Write the whole javascript code in common_layout.js
Add every statement using id of that div and add this file with main layout.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#header').html('<b>Header</b><ul><li>First Link</li><li>Second Link</li></ul> ');
});
```

UPDATE: One of my favorite post from TutsPlus : [Best practices when working with JS Templates](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/best-practices-when-working-with-javascript-templates/)

Comment: Could you please share some demo link that how to use JS template?

Comment: @user2130962 : Please find the updated paragraph in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just started with this application. You can think of using client side java script frameworks like - AngularJS. It would be lot easier to maintain the code and solve such trivial issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object` tag like this:

```
<object name="header" type="text/html" data="header.html"></object>
```